# excel : determine if a combination of several cells exists and output result

Tags: excel

Considering the following data :

sheet1 (customers)

```
  A
0 customer_name
1 john
2 kevin
3 mickael
```

sheet2 (products)

```
  A
0 product_name
1 book
2 ball
3 game
```

sheet3 (orders)

```
  A             B
0 customer_name product_name
1 john          book
2 john          game
3 mickael       ball
```

I would like to know for each combination of customer and product if an order has been ordered and display it in the sheet1 to get something like that :

sheet1 (customers updated )

```
  A              B    C    D    
0 customer_name  book ball game
1 john           1    0    1
2 kevin          0    0    0
3 mickael        0    1    0
```

I know how to do that with "code" (by doing a macro in vba or a small exe in c# that will update the file), but I want to do it (if its possible) by just setting a formula inside my sheet (fyi, I can put the 3 inputs in the same sheet if needed, that's not a constraint

Updated :

with the previous configuration described, I have put the following formula in sheet1 B2 : =COUNTIFS(Sheet3!$A:$A;$A2;Sheet3!$B:$B;B$2), and when running the formula and extending it to every cell in my sheet I am getting everywhere the value #NAME? (I've translated if from french so I am not sure if its the right error in english). I think where I am making a mistake is that I am not using sheet2, how can I say first to "do all the combinations possible of customers insheet1 and products in sheet2 and look for those combinations in sheet3, knowing that I am in sheet1 and that I want to display the result like aking before?

Comment: If you can put the 3 inputs in the same sheet, then use COUNTIFS.

Comment: I will have to add a formula for each combination possible, there is no way to make something dynamically that will make all the combinations possible between customers and products?

Comment: Use absolute referencing and reference the customer name column and the product name row... `=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A:$A,$A1,Sheet2!$B:$B,B$1)`. Or use a pivot table.

Comment: will it be possible to have a more detailled answer?

Comment: Can you try that formula?

Comment: the formula is throwing me an error, I cannot reference another sheet in it

Comment: Then you could write it manually, selecting the sheet.

Comment: ok, but could you explain the formula, I am trying to understand it according to my example, and I can't see why you're searching in the sheet2, wouldn't have to be sheet3?

Comment: Yes sorry sheet3 (typo on my part).

Comment: ok, honestly I've tried to understand and implement it, according to my example, and I'm still getting error, so a detailed answer according to my example would be welcome, if not, nevermind, I will try to find another solution. Thanks a lot though

Comment: Please [edit] your question with how you're trying it, and the problems you're having, thanks.

Comment: I have updated it with what I am doing according to your formula (adapted to my case)

Comment: `NB.SI.ENS` looks like the French equivalent of `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: Yes I know, thats what I am using, I just put the english version on my stack post to avoid unrelated confusion, but thats not tje reason of the error Im getting

Comment: Got it - but I need a [reprex] in order to help.

Comment: I dont understand, the input data is not enough? These are the exact 3 sheets I am using and I described the final output I would like to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet3!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet3!$B:$B,B$1)
```

[image]

Comment: I am not using sheet2 with this formula, I will miss product that have never been ordered no?

Comment: This assumes that you add all products from sheet2 to sheet1... you can do that with TRANSPOSE.